# В чем причина ошибки net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, form

Пытаюсь создать форму для отправки сообщения из формы в телеграм-бота, запускаю код в расширении LiveServer, но по какой-то причине это не работает.
PHP-код:

```
<?php
    $content = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $content .= " <b> $key </b>: <i> $value </i> \n";
        }
    }
    if (trim($content)) {
        $content = "<b> From Site: </b> \n".$content;
        $apiToken = ""; // Вставьте сюда API-токен бота
        $data = [
            "chat_id" => "", // Вставьте сюда chat_id
            "text" => $content,
            "parse_mode" => "HTML",
        ];
        $response = file_get_contents(
            "https://api.telegram.org/bot/$apiToken/sendMessage?".http_build_query($data)
        );
    }
?>
```

JS-код:

```
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   const form = document.querySelector(".send-message-form");
   form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      sendMessage(form);
   });

   async function sendMessage(form) {
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      if (formData) {
         const url = "sendMessage.php";
         const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
         });
         if (response.ok) {
            form.reset();
            alert("Сообщение успешно отправлено!");
         } else {
            alert("Ошибка :(");
         }
      }
   }
});
```

В чём может быть проблема? Может из-за того, что я запускаю скрипты на Live Server?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю ошибка в простом. Надо писать не

```
bot/$apiToken
```

а вот так:

```
bot{$apiToken}
```

то есть токен идёт сразу после текста "bot"

Comment: А может из-за того, что я запускаю php скрипт на стороне клиента? У меня нет установленного сервера

Comment: Live Server - это сервер, судя из последнего слова

Comment: Если там не настроена обработка php, то можно расширение браузера использовать https://youtu.be/joxLj3O_QGo  .... ну либо непосредственно в vscode ещё какое-то расширение скачать для запуска сервера под пыху..........но проблема тут именно в строке должна быть всё равно

Answer (score -1):

Запрос на отправку сообщения предполагает метод `POST` https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/reference/sendmessage

Вы используете `file_get_contents`, который имитирует метод `GET` - отсюда ошибка

Вам стоит использовать библиотеку HTTP клиента, например, https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Это неправильный ответ. а ссылку на доку вы привели не официальной доки, а какой-то библы

Comment: Это не сервер, а расширение в vs code для автоматического обновления страницы

Comment: и все-таки попробуйте заслать постом, хотя бы через постман

Comment: @abu да не в этом дело... я вам, как человек, который работал с ботами телеги и сделал нотификаторы, пишу.....никакие "всё же" тут не помогут.